# Recurrence relation of number of comparisons in binary search

Tags: algorithm, binary-search, recurrence

I have doubt about recurrence relation for number of comparisons in binary search.

I read that recurrence can be written as T(n) = T(n/2) + 1 in this website http://faculty.simpson.edu/lydia.sinapova/www/cmsc250/LN250_Weiss/L14-RecRel.htm

According to me it should be T(n) = T(n/2) + 2, as in worst case the element might not be present in the array and we end up doing 2 comparisons in each pass.

Please tell me whether I am right or wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right.

IMHO, `compare a b` means we know `a=b`, `a>b` or `a<b` at the same time. That is to say, 1 comparison may have 3 different results.

But for programming languages. We have to use 2 comparisons.

```
if mid == x:      found it!          # 1st
else if mid < x:  search right       # 2nd
else:             search left
```

You mean the `==` and `<` are 2 comparisons.

It does not affect the result though. Because we use big O notation to represent the complexity. It is just a matter of constant, but `O` usually don't care about it.

According to [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem). Either `+1` or `+2` will result the same complexity `O(log n)`.

What we want is usually a limit (`Big-O`), not a mathematical equation precise result.

I think what matters here is that `1` and `2` are both constant time. We can also split `==`, `>` into machine instructions, and it may be greater than `2`. Or maybe some programming languages or CPU utilize the comparison, it only cost `1` comparison. But it does not matter here when doing asymptotic analysis.

---

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis

Comment: Yes, I do agree that when calculating time complexity it doesn't matter as it's just a constant. But if we want to count the number of comparisons then the number of comparisons might change depending on the recurrence relation.